# What color swatch to use for cut lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, signage

I'm designing some signage that will be printed and cut with a CNC machine. What would be the best color swatch to use for the lines that should be cut?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The industry standard for die-cut lines on laser cutting machines are as follows:

- **Red stroke: RGB (255,0,0)**
- **Stroke weight: to 0.01mm / 0.25 pt**

That being said, it's always a good idea to double check with the company you're planning on sending the vector files to just to make sure they use the same standards.

Sources:

[*File Setup GUIDELINES: CUT LINES - (red)*](https://onlinelasercutting.com.au/file-setup/)

[*Drawing Resources: Adobe Illustrator CS® - Laser cutting lines*](http://www.cutlasercut.com/resources/drawing-guidelines/adobe-illustrator-cs-r)

[*How to set a dieline (Keyline, die-cut) to spot colour?: FOLD/SCORE LINES*](http://www.smcprint.ie/index.php/about-us/blog/36-how-to-set-a-dieline-keyline-die-cut-to-spot-colour)

Comment: Thanks, does the same generally apply when its a mechanical knife/saw?

Comment: It's possible depending on the software the cutter is using. You're best bet would be to contact the company just to be 100% certain.

Answer (score 2):

This may be an outdated method considering almost all production facilities have the programs to access and export the final art files as they like, but I was taught to:

1. create a spot color named "die-line"
2. export as postscript "seperation host-based" (include spot color "die-line")
3. export as postscript "composite"
4. convert to PDF using acrobat distiller
5. send to production