# Illustrator: how to prepare artwork for laser cutter

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, laser-cutting

I'm working on a laser cutting project where I have to cut out using an RGB red line at the size of 0.001 in. I used Image trace to make an outline of the image, but I can't change the color to RGB red, or the thickness of the outline. I need it to be RGB with a 0.001 in thickness, or the laser cutter will not cut it out.

[image: This is the image I want to make an outline of]
[image: This is the outcome of the outline option in Image Trace]

Comment: That's **not** an "outline" that is a series of shapes with fills. If you want strokes, you'll have to do something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select your artwork.
2. Hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to swap the black fill with a black stroke.
3. Hit <kbd>F6</kbd> to open up the Color panel, set to RGB from the top arrow menu and type 255,0,0 as seen below.
4. Hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open up the Stroke panel and type `0.001 in` in the *Weight* field.
5. Also read the answers here: [What color swatch to use for cut lines?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83118/what-color-swatch-to-use-for-cut-lines)

[image]